# When to add "the", "a" or when not to add "the" or "a"?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference (or correct way of saying it) between the followings:

1. "Review plan" vs "Review a plan" vs "Review the plan"?
2. "Agree on plan" vs "Agree on a plan" vs "Agree on the plan"
3. "Implementation of the plans" vs "Implementation of plans? vs "Implementation of plan"?

I suppose it boils down to when do you add "the" or "a" or not add it at all?

Comment: Each is appropriate in certain contexts, and each covers much the same situation. In bullet points, agenda items, or headlines, for instance, articles are usually taken for granted, so "Agree on plan" or "Review plan" would serve there. In speech, _the plan_ indicates (a) that there's only one plan under discussion and (b) that it's already been mentioned in the discourse. _A plan_, on the other hand, is used for the first mention of the plan into the discourse (_He presented a plan for the advertising_); after that, it's definite because it's been mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an academic answer, but a practical one based on the English language as it is used.

Review plan - this could be a name for an existing plan designed to review something. The name of the plan is 'Review Plan'. Or, it is shorthand or note form (perhaps in a 'To Do' list)

Review a plan - referring to a plan (any plan) being reviewed

Agree on plan - shorthand, note form (wouldn't be spoken). The correct usage in normal speech or writing is one of the other two (both are equally correct)

Implementation of the plans - the correct usage in formal writing or normal speech. The other two are both note form or shorthand.